# 2017 MacBook Pro starts with a question mark folder when there is less than 50% charge and when it wakes up from sleep. Why?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, battery, sleep-wake, charging

My 2017 MacBook Pro reboots with a question mark folder when the charge is below 50%. When I connect my charger, it starts normally.

I also noticed when the MacBook Pro goes to sleep and wakes up, it shows the same problem. Also, it becomes really hot when I use heavy software like Final Cut Pro and starts hanging.

I went to the Apple Store and they asked me to reinstall macOS, which didn't work. The common issue with the question mark problem is the SSD, but in my case its not the SSD. I ran a speed test and the SSD is working properly.

Do any of you guys have a solution?

Comment: Did you try to hold down the alt/option key when you restarted your Mac?

Comment: Just because a speed test worked fine doesn’t rule out the SSD isn’t faulty. For some, the internal components could work in some situations and not others, i.e. a slight bump here or there, or as you said it doesn’t work below a certain charge. But if a reinstall of macOS doesn’t fix it, I’d still be inclined to believe it’s the SSD (as the question mark on the folder indicates a SSD/HD fault), the alternative is that there’s a logic board fault.

Comment: Yes I did, My SSD is seen. I even tried reinstalling the OS, PVRAM, NVRAM, SMAC, everything has been reset. This is definitely a hardware issue, but don't know what component is malfunctioning.

Comment: Yeah, I went to Icare, without opening, just because the question mark folder occured they said its the SSD's fault and asking me half the price of the laptop, i can get the components from somewhere, but i need to know exactly what part has gone wrong for me to solve it. I would stick to SSD if it wasn't heating, its getting really hot when i use a software. And i would also like to add that both the ends of my charger cable has turned yellow and at times my laptop becomes hot just by charging .

Comment: By any chance is it a 13” MacBook Pro? Apple has a repair program for mid 2017-2018 13” MBPs with 128 or 256GB SSDs. See here https://support.apple.com/13-inch-macbook-pro-solid-state-drive-service

Comment: @AVelj Yes, I have Macbook pro 2017 13", but it says my mac is not eligible for this program.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this unchecking the option "Put the hard disk to sleep when possible" under System Preferences > Energy Saver, both in "Battery" and "Power adapter" tabs.